# SAX startElement is never called

Tags: java, android, xml, sax

I'm trying to use SAX to parse an XML but it happens that the Handler's startElement() is never called. I do not have any clues why it doesnt work.

This is my code

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

public class ChangePasswordXMLParser {
    public static void parseXML(InputStream xml) {
        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            ChangePasswordHandler handler = new ChangePasswordHandler();
            saxParser.parse(xml, handler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static class ChangePasswordHandler extends DefaultHandler {
        boolean bfReturn;

        public ChangePasswordHandler() {

        }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("return")) {
                bfReturn = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            if (bfReturn) {
                AuthenticateUserResult user = SessionManager.getInstance().getUser();
                String value = new String(ch, start, length);
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new AlterarSenhaEvent(value));
                bfReturn = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is and XML Input example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENC:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <NS1:ChangePasswordResponse xmlns:NS1="urn:exemple">
      <return xsi:type="xsd:string">03351-0</return>
    </NS1:ChangePasswordResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I did see in other topic here in stackoverflow that may be the imports, but my imports seems fine to me.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure startElement isn't called? insert a sout or set a breakpoint. Your code seems to be correct.

Comment: @dr_debug I'm pretty sure. I already did it and nothing happens!

Comment: can you post an example xml? I'll have a look

Comment: I added an xml example to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You set `AlterarSenhaHandler` instead of `PasswordHandler`.

So `PasswordHandler` is never called.

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("return")) {
        System.out.println("inside return");
    }
}
```

proofs that your code is valid

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. My original code has some portuguese words on it, I just forget to change it when I translate it, already update it on the post